# Unzip nested zip files with powershell

Tags: powershell, zip, unzip

I have the following structure
Folder\zip\zip1, zip2, zip3

I would like to extract all the files contained in the zip1, zip2, zip3 in a single folder.

I tried with Expand-Archive, but could not get beyond the zip folder.

Answer (score 1):

If the structure looks like this:

```
/Folder/
  /Foo.zip
    /1.zip
    /2.zip
```

Then the simplest way is:

```
Expand-Archive -LiteralPath 'c:\folder\Foo.zip' -DestinationPath 'C:\temp\Foo-expanded\'

# Get all the nested zip files, and expand them to the same folder:
Get-ChildItem 'C:\folder\expanded\*.zip' | 
  Expand-Archive -DestinationPath 'C:\folder\SingleFolder\'
```

Use `Expand-Archive -Force` if you want to overwrite existing files.